# Text size in standart printable points

Tags: actionscript-3, size, textfield, point

How can I set the text size (inside TextField) in standart CSS/printable points? According to the manual:

> fontSize - Only the numeric part of the value is used. Units (px, pt)
>   are not parsed; pixels and points are equivalent.

As far as I understand, 1 pixel may be equal to 1 point only in 72 PPI case. So, actionscript just operating pixels (not the real points). My trouble is to get the actual text size that I can print. Any advices or solutions are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

SWF is measured in pixels, moreover, is scalable, so 1 pixel can be 1 point now, 2 points a bit later (scaleY=scaleX=2), and an undefined number another bit later (removed from stage without dereferencing). In short, for AS there are NO "real points" since it does not know a thing about printers, while it knows about displays.